# How to prove I am out of the country - Ministry of External affairs, India and Government of France

Tags: france, india

I was planning on posting this in the "chat" section but I thought maybe it is a worthwhile question.

**Here is some background**

- I am an Indian citizen in the USA on an F1  visa.
- I have received a job offer/convention d'accueil from a French research lab (in France)
- The French lab/French government want me to produce **two original birth certificates that are [apostiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille_Convention)** for health insurance, social security purposes.
- The Ministry of external (MEA) affairs in India **[will apostil](http://www.mea.gov.in/legalization-of-documents.htm)** my birth certificates for me... but...

  - The MEA wants me to appear in person with my birth cert.
  - If I am to have someone else do this on my behalf (viz., my father), they would need me to *prove* that I am out of the country.
  - The one approach they recommended is to **fax** a copy of my passport, I-94 and US F1 Visa copies to an Indian fax machine. The idea is that the facsimile would have a US telephone number associated with it.

**The problem**

- Not withstanding the lack of wisdom on the MEA's part that one can spoof US phone numbers via online fax websites etc., I am unable to fax documents from my little town in the Upper Midwest of the USA due to technical difficulties and the fact that my town has only **one** (that is correct ladies and gentlemen!) fax machine. The nearest fax machine is about 6 hours away.

**The question**

What other "legal" (want of a better word) methods may I use to prove that I am in the USA and that I CANNOT appear in person at the MEA in India to get my birth certificates apostilled?  NO, I cannot appear in person at the MEA in India. For a variety of reasons, I am unable to travel the 6 hours to the nearest fax machine and unfortunately this would appear to be non-negotiable.

Comment: What about the online fax services you mentioned? Since you really are in the US, there wouldn't be anything deceptive about that I think. If a proper fax machine or scanner are not available, you should at least be able to find someone with a smartphone and have them take of picture of the document.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans I didn't want to do that since the Indian MEA is short on imagination and does not appreciate "technology". So it would be better to deign to their wishes or I won't get my documents attested and will end up losing a lucrative job! `:(`

Comment: You can't prove you can't appear in person in India because you can (unless you're a refugee, whcih would significantly change many things). You can argue that fullfilling formal requirements produces unreasonable costs (both material and immaterial) for you. I really can't understand what are those birth certificates for. Your passport should contain birthdate, and it's an official document confirming when you were born. The fact you were born is already confirmed by your existence. Anyway, wish you luck fighting with bureaucracy.

Comment: Anyway, I can't understand how can it be you're in condition that would enable you to travel to France, but makes 6 hour drive unbearable.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Try driving in the whiteout snow conditions we have `=)`. I travel to france in the summer. After the thaw.

Comment: @drN OK so the actual problem is, you're cut off from the world for the next few weeks? It's a good reason, I'm afraid, however, it could be hard to imagine for officers in India...

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I know what you mean.People are struck with disbelief when I tell them about it. It's just a way of life here. Yes, it is difficult for them to imagine in India at the MEA.. and apparently in France... but nevertheless, it apparently is *my problem* and I have to solve it.

Comment: @drN but actually, MEA doesn't want to have a scan of your password, but only a proof that you are in USA? If they have some electronic system for passports, they should know, you have left India and never cross the border back from that time?

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Yes, but like I implied, there is a severe disconnect between international travel records and the insular "Babus" (bureaucrats in India).

Comment: @drN The general outlook in France regarding immigration matters is that everything is *your* problem.

Comment: You should give [online fax services](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/how-can-i-send-one-off-faxes-to-a-usa-recipient-online) a try. Apparently some of them are even free. At worst MEA will get wise and reject it, but I doubt they would notice.

Comment: Does nobody in your town have an old computer lying around with a fax modem in it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any issue with using an online system to send the fax. You are in the US so you are not breaking any rules. That said, you may not want to give a random internet company an electronic copy your personal documents.

Many stores and frequently hotels have fax machines. I would be surprised if the nearest fax machine was really 6 hours away. In years past, I often sent faxes from hotels that I was not staying at. It might be harder to convince someone to send an international fax for you. Have you asked at your nearest hotel? What at the nearest hospital? It is amazing the extent to which people will take advantage of their employers for friends or a $20 bill.

Only a slightly more expensive option is to buy a fax machine since they are pretty cheap these days. For example, [Staples](http://www.staples.com/fax/directory_fax?sby=1&rpp=18&pn=1&sr=true) sells one for $40 with free shipping, and if you search longer you will likely be able to find a better deal. This seems cheaper than a trip to India or a 6 hour drive. You could ideally then resell the machine after you are done with it. If not you could donate it to someone in your town since they seem in need of a fax machine.

Comment: Hospital: 100 miles away (we only have a local clinic), no *staples* unless I drive 6 hours ( need documents faxed asap so cannot go on internet shopping trip), cannot buy fax machine in this town. Yes, I live in the middle of nowhere. Hotel=good idea. Will check.

Comment: Local hotel = "sorry we don't do international faxes! have a good day!" I did tell them that it was an emergency and that I would pay them for it.

Comment: @drN It would surprise me if the local clinic didn't have a fax machine. It wouldn't surprise me if you could get next day delivery from Staples although you might be far enough out there that it would take a few days.

Comment: +1 for your comment about "town needs fax machine"! `-several million` to town that is completely deficient-ish.

Comment: I always thoguht that fax is an object of the past and not really used anymore. I was mistaken apparently

Comment: My VOIP provider (in Poland) offered sending faxes, but I think I've never actually used that option...

Answer (score 5):

This is what **[consulates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consul_%28representative%29)** are for.

You should contact the [Indian consulate for the area in which you reside](https://www.indianembassy.org/pages.php?id=27), and ask them what is required from you for them to provide the certification their bosses at home asked you for. Most likely they'll ask you to appear personally in the consulate office. If you live far they may provide another solution. But basically - that is *literally* what they're there for.

Answer (score 3):

Take a picture of you holding the local newspaper (date, and place), your passport and/or the e-mail they sent to you asking for proving your are out of India. Send it to your parents, and bring it to the MEA office.

Hope you the best.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines as well!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can provide notarized affidavit and there will be notarized stamp on it and will provide a proof and you are in US
2. Along with 1. get notarized and send your passport/visa/i94 copies by overnight mail.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest fax machine would cost less then $35 and can be ordered online to be delivered at your place. Just hook it up with your phone line and send a fax from your own number if you are not comfortable sending an electronic fax.

$35 is going to be a lot cheaper then making a 6 hour journey or going to the nearest consulate.